# Javascript new window for video not resizing in IE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following code for a javascript pop-up window that embeds a youtube video on my website.

```
<script language="JavaScript"> function openAndroid22Window()
 {
   NewWindow=window.open("http://v4m.mobi/php/video_demo_frame.php?
   vid=http://www.youtube.com/embed/1-VsX8qMVFo?rel=0&width=640&height=510",   
   "awindow","width=668,height=548,scrollbars=yes");
 }
</script>
<li><a href="javascript:openAndroid22Window()">Installation on Android</a></li>
```

The problem is that in all browsers, except IE, the window can be resized. Why won't it resize /maximize in IE ?

Comment: It's working on ie9, which version did you test it on?

Comment: tested in ie9. when I added the resizable=yes, it worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `resizable=yes`

```
function openAndroid22Window()
{
       NewWindow=window.open("http://google.com", "awindow", "width=668,height=548,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");
}
```

Tested in IE, [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/BMm9a/).

Comment: Thanks man, you are super. Didn't expect it to be that simple