# Javascript text box not expandable in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I work in web QA and have created a javascript tool that many team members use. Sometime we get tickets where we need to check numerous links at one time. So my tool allows the user to paste in links and click a button to open in numerous tabs. In Firefox the window is expandable however if used in IE it is not. Is there something I can add to make the window expandable in IE? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**JS**

```
 function doSomething() {
    var urlsTogether = document.getElementById("demLinks").value;
    var urls = urlsTogether.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
       window.open(urls[i]);
    }
 }
```

**HTML**

```
  <font color="black"> Type links here!: </font>
  <textarea id="demLinks">
  </textarea>
  <button onclick="doSomething();">Open dem Pages</button>
```

Comment: I think that this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215865/javascript-new-window-for-video-not-resizing-in-ie `window.open("http://google.com", "awindow", "width=668,height=548,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");`

Comment: Don't use the font tag, it has been deprecated for ages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of window.open allows for specifications. The following allows the window to be resized:

```
window.open("http://www.cnn.com/", "_blank", "resizable=yes");
```

Read more about the specifications [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)